# How to handle Stripe Webhook?

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, webhooks

I have added a webhook endpoint for Stripe and I'm able to receive the webhook, but how can I handle the information send from Stripe?

E.g. I want to send an e-mail to my customer about the successful payment. I'm using MailerSend, I know how to send an e-mail but how can I initiate this process?

**Webhook Controller**

```
public function webhook(Request $request) {
        $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('sk_XXX');

        // This is your Stripe CLI webhook secret for testing your endpoint locally.
        $endpoint_secret = 'whsec_XXX';
        
        $payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
        $sig_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'];
        $event = null;
        
        try {
          $event = \Stripe\Webhook::constructEvent(
            $payload, $sig_header, $endpoint_secret
          );
        } catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
          // Invalid payload
          http_response_code(400);
          exit();
        } catch(\Stripe\Exception\SignatureVerificationException $e) {
          // Invalid signature
          http_response_code(400);
          exit();
        }
        
        // Handle the event
        switch ($event->type) {
          case 'checkout.session.completed':
            $session = $event->data->object;
          default:
            echo 'Received unknown event type ' . $event->type;
        }

        http_response_code(200);
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Tried to add code inside the webhook case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the test, not for the production.

1. Install ngrok and start the test domain `ngrok http 8888`.
2. Copy forwarding url
3. Paste ngrok URL in stripe settings (for production insert the real domain)
4. Perform the required action
5. Catch it in our `webhook(Request $request)` method.
6. After successful validation check, send an email or something else after the try/catch.

You may also find the [package](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-stripe-webhooks) helpful.

```php
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/apikeys
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_26PHem9AhJZvU623DfE1x4sd');

$payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$event = null;

try {
    $event = \Stripe\Event::constructFrom(
        json_decode($payload, true)
    );
} catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
    // Invalid payload
    abort(400);
}

// Handle the event
switch ($event->type) {
    case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
        $paymentIntent = $event->data->object; // contains a \Stripe\PaymentIntent
        handlePaymentIntentSucceeded($paymentIntent);
        break;
    case 'payment_method.attached':
        $paymentMethod = $event->data->object; // contains a \Stripe\PaymentMethod
        handlePaymentMethodAttached($paymentMethod);
        break;
    // ... handle other event types
    default:
        echo 'Received unknown event type ' . $event->type;
}
```

Comment: So I can actually just put the MailerSend code in the case checkout.session.complete? Or do I need to create another function with (e.g.) handleCheckoutSessionCompleted? Sorry, I'm just trying to understand it.

Comment: If this is all you need from webhook then yes, if there will be more logic - then it makes sense to put it in a separate class.

Comment: Okay, and to use date from the webhook I can just do e.g. $session->id?

Comment: event payload contains a `created` date did you mean that?

Comment: Little typo by me, I mean data, for example I want to use the email for the MailerSend mail I send can I just use {{ $session->mail }}?

Comment: you can use the mail sending facade `Mail::to($email)->send(new WebhookCompleted($event));`. I don't understand how you want to send mail through a session